# How do you create an Azure AD Dynamic Device Group based on the Intune Device Enrollment Manager which enrolled the device via AutoPilot?

Tags: entra-id, microsoft-intune

I am trying to create an Azure AD dynamic device group which contains all devices enrolled by X user 'Associated User'?
This user is the Device Enrollment Manager user **DEM** which allowed me to enroll up to 1K devices.

Comment: Some folks are doing this through Powershell. "Creating Device Groups Based on User Groups with Graph API" https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/smeems/2018/05/11/user-based-device-groups/

Comment: @NathanHartley Sadly your link is offline. Google had those in cache. Here's the download link for [Add-SpecificDevicestoAADGroup.ps1](https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/Create-Device-Group-Based-73eb063e) Here is the [Google Cache Site](https://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:pYooQsWJ6k8J:https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/smeems/2018/05/11/user-based-device-groups/).

Answer (score 0):

To create a Microsoft Intune dynamic device group, you can refer to this [docs](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/intune/groups-add)

Comment: How exactly does that doc show how to create a Dynamic Group based on devices enrolled by a particular Device Enrollment Manager? The DEM doc makes it sound as though device policy could be applied based on the DEM account used when enrolling the device. https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/intune/device-enrollment-manager-enroll

Answer (score 0):

You can't create dynamic group based on the data from Intune, because this data is not populated into AAD.
So there is no OOTB way to do this I am affraid.
Your only option is to use scheduled PowerShell script which would add/remove devices to some custom group base on Intune attributes.